# Cannot select one record that exists MYSQL PHP 7 Angular 6

Tags: php, mysql, angular

This appears to be a simple matter.  I have a list of caseworkers and I simply need to select one based upon the initials of the person.  There are no duplicates in the table.  I am using PHP 7.3 and Angular 6

There are about 10 rows in the users table.  Some of the initials are 'RB', 'JTB', 'JLI' and 'AEM'

AEM does not work.  If I change the user to any of the other user inits, it works fine, but it can NOT locate AEM.  I event tried changing the inits to AM, still, no go.

In phpmyadmin, I manually type in the search query using the inits AEM and it works fine.

```
<?php
require_once './header.php';
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
@$casew = $request->casew;
$qa = "SELECT name, email, inits FROM users WHERE inits = '$casew'";
$res = mysqli_query($con, $qa);

if(!$res) {
    die("Database Query Failed."  . mysqli_error($con) . " CW");
}  

$array = mysqli_fetch_all($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($array);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

---

```
Angular 6
getCW() {
const casew = { casew: this.client.caseworker };
this.http.post('[SERVERNAME]/DBAccess/getCW.php', JSON.stringify(casew))
.subscribe((res: any) => {
  this.cw = res;
  console.log(res, casew);
});
```

}

In the console log, if I use any of the other inits, it works fine.  If I select AEM I get 
null {casew: "AEM"}

Using RB for example I get 
[{…}] {casew: "RB"}

Any thoughts or ideas are very much appreciated.

Comment: why does your API end-point look like `../DBAccess/getCW.php`? The hole purpose of using angularis to separate backend and frontend and you are using angular inside php.

Comment: They are separate files, PHP on the server and Angular local. The endpoint is not as is shown I truncated it for privacy reasons.  Sorry for the confusion there.

Comment: Interestingly, if I change the inits to AXM and run a simple if($inits == 'AEM'){$casew = 'AXM'}  It works.......

Comment: There is no magic. What characters (language, encoding) your "AEM" in?

Comment: I know little of this.  Always used the default, latin1_swedish_ci and have not had this problem.   Is that the issue??